# Different parameter (add and remove)

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery code.

```
jQuery.ajax({

type:"GET",

url:"/?favorite=add",

data:{postID:postidHash},

cache:false,

timeout:1E4})
```

But I have 2 parameter. add and remove. This code working for add but How can I do work for both parameter?

My php paramteter url:

For add: http:// website.com/?favorite=add&postID=3283

For remove: http:// website.com/?favorite=remove&postID=3283

Edit: PHP Code

```
$link = '<a class="wpfp_link '.$class." title="'.$opt.'" href="'.get_bloginfo("url").'/?favorite='.$action.'&amp;postID='. $post_id . '" rel="nofollow">'. favorites_count() .'</a>';
```

My javascript codes full.

```
function likePost(postidHash){
if(typeof postidHash==="undefined"||postidHash===""){
displayError("Post not found.");return}
jQuery.ajax({type:"GET",url:"/?favorite=add",data:{postID:postidHash},cache:false,timeout:1E4})
.error(handleAjaxError)
.success(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){likePostCardCallback(postidHash,data,textStatus,jqXHR)})}
```

Comment: You're going to need to share a lot more code so we can see how this works along with clarifying what "work for both parameters" means.

Comment: what's the relation to php here if there's no code to support the question?

Comment: Please share more code.

Comment: i added more codes. sorry for my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending `postID` in GET request to the url you can do the same with favorite as well.

**ADD**

```
jQuery.ajax({

type:"GET",

url:"/",

data:{postID:postidHash,favorite:"add"},

cache:false,

timeout:1E4})
```

**REMOVE**

```
jQuery.ajax({

type:"GET",

url:"/",

data:{postID:postidHash,favorite:"remove"},

cache:false,

timeout:1E4})
```

Or instead you can bind the add/remove on a button and make generic code.

**Generic**

```
var action = GET BUTTON ACTION HERE;

jQuery.ajax({

type:"GET",

url:"/",

data:{postID:postidHash,favorite:action},

cache:false,

timeout:1E4})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var varFavorite = "";
if( condition )
    varFavorite  = "add";
else
    varFavorite  = "remove";

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/",
    data:{postID:postidHash,favorite:varFavorite},
    cache:false,
    timeout:1E4
})
```